Is slope $m=(y-y_1)/(x-x_1)$ same as $y-y_1 = m(x-x_1)$?
My question is rather subtle. In the context of functional equivalence, that is, they both having same domain and same output. The prior is undefined at the point $(x_1,y_1), m=0/0$. But multiplying both sides with $(x-x_1)$ gives us the equation of straight line. How are they both same, in this context? Secondly, How is multiplying with $(x-x_1)$ justified?

Point-slope form comes from the slope formula. You can only do the multiplication, of course, if $x \neq x_1.$

Multiplying by $(x-x_1)$ is fine.  The problem is division by $(x-x_1)$ when $x=x_1$.

Thanks for the responses. So, what can be done about the point (x1,y1)? M is not defined for the point (x1,y1), How did mathematicians resolve this problem?

@ELIZACOLINPOWELL basically the second formula identifies the line itself, as the set of all points $(x, y)$ satisfying it. Of course when you substitute $x = x1$ and $y = y1$ in the formula, you get $0m = 0$, which is a true statement and making $(x_1, y_1)$ satisfying it.
